# Want to play twilio media stream in browser (real time) via node.js websocket

Tags: twilio, mediastream

I want to play twilio media stream in browser in real time. For this I am using websocket to send twilio stream from node.js server to browser. I am converting the twilio media stream by using wavefile npm with the following code :-

```
            // Server Side Code
            const wav = new WaveFile();
            wav.fromScratch(1, 8000, '8m', Buffer.from(item.audioPayload, "base64"));
            wav.fromMuLaw();
            wav.toSampleRate(44100);
            let dataURI = wav.toDataURI();
            item.audioPayload = dataURI;
            this.sendAgentMessage(item, this.connection);
```

And at the browser side I am playing audio using this :-

```
            // Client side code
            var snd = new Audio(message.audioPayload);
            snd.play();
```

Now while playing the audio I am getting very much noise and distortion.

Please help me with this.

Comment: When you receive the media message over the websocket, the audio is `event.media.payload` not `audioPayload`. Perhaps that's where this is going wrong?

Comment: @philnash the content for `item.audioPayload` is same as `event.media.payload`

Comment: Are you able to save the wav file to disk and play it successfully outside of the browser? I'm wondering whether this is an issue in your server-side code that is converting the audio or in the client-side where you are trying to play it back.

Comment: Yes the wav file is working successfully in server side. But not working in browser.

Comment: Rather than sending this as a dataURI, it is probably better to send the audio as binary data over the websocket and then play it using the Web Audio API, rather than creating `Audio` objects. Is that something you have tried?

Comment: How I can I convert the mulaw to binary and play on browser ?

Comment: I mean, the file is a binary file, you wrote the code to turn it to a data URI. So try turning it to a buffer then sending it over the websocket. And then look into how to play a buffer with the Web Audio API for the playback part.